# "Teaching" the client what endpoint to use for graphql

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql

I am adapting [this](https://github.com/SimonDegraeve/hapi-graphql/issues/5) to work within the context of a hapi server that also defines many other "conventional" api endpoints. If I want to define an endpoint for graphql (similar to the README) in this way:

```
route: {
  path: '/graphql',
  config: {}
}
```

...is there then additional configuration that needs to happen in the client side code to "teach" the react/relay app what path to make their post/get requests to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Relay Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-network-layer.html#content). The endpoint your mentioned /graphql is what relay by default uses to communicate with graphql server. If you need to specify a different server and endpoint you would do:

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://example.com/graphql')
)
```

to modify Relay's default graphql endpoint and server.

Comment: Thanks...side comment/question - any info on the `application/graphql` mime-type? Is this something that Relay uses in its requests? I have seen evidence of this mime-type in both an express and hapi server implementation of graphql. I am hoping Relay uses a standard mime-type in its requests to `/graphql`

Comment: I am not 100% sure, even though I implemented one or two relay websites, but all I can say that, relay sends queries in JSON format, namely, a json object with 2 keys, query and variables. So the mime-type request header is application/json. However, I know that same graphql server will work with just the graphql query, with mime-type is application/graphql. So it depends on how you form the query. Simply let relay use json header, and you will use graphql header especially for debugging the server with a HTTP client